# Copy from one workbook into another using a file path name

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run a macro using an *existing* workbook that 1) opens a different workbook I'll call *other* 2) copies values from *other* workbook 3) pastes values from *other* into *existing* workbook and 4) closes *other* workbook. Below is the code I have so far. Is there a way to better define or set y? My code works except I am not able to close *other* and I think if I had y better defined I could just use something like y.close. Thanks!

```
Dim x As Worksheet
Dim y As Worksheet

Set x = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("File44")

Workbooks.Open (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\File44.xlsm")
Workbooks("File44.xlsm").Activate

Set y = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("File44 - Detail")
LastRow = y.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

y.Range("A15:CQ" & LastRow).Copy
x.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
```

Comment: you need to get an workbook object than access the worksheets in it.  Also give your variable names something meaningful so you can distinguish what they are.

Comment: Do you have an example you could provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Untested**

```
Sub Chris2015()

Dim other As Workbook
Dim fromWS As Worksheet
Dim toWS As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long

Set toWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("File44") 'pasting to this worksheet
Set other = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.path & "\File44.xlsm")
Set fromWS = other.Sheets("File44 - Detail")

lastRow = fromWS.Range("A" & fromWS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

toWS.Range("A2:CQ" & lastRow - 13).Value2 = fromWS.Range("A15:CQ" & lastRow).Value2 'hope I did math right XD

other.Close savechanges:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Worked great. Thank you!